# How to get user profile image URL with Tweepy / Twitter API V2

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I've been trying to figure out the Twitter API v2 so I can pull the Profile Image URL of a specific username/ID, but I am not having any luck.

**Here's my code. Anyone know where I'm going wrong?!**

```
import tweepy

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token='bearer')

tweets = client.get_user(username = 'jack', user_fields=['profile_image_url'])
print(tweets)
```

**Response:**

`Response(data=<User id=12 name=jack username=jack>, includes={}, errors=[], meta={})`

Answer (score 1):

try with user id's instead

```
user_ids = [2244994945, 6253282] #TwitterDev&API profile images

tweets = client.get_user(ids = user_ids, user_fields=['profile_image_url'])
```

[Tweepy.org Examples for APIv2](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/examples.html)